# How to remove counting numbers from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

How can I remove counting numbers from the array?

```
array = ['1 1.60\n2 3.90\n3 5.40', '1 3.45\n2 3.10\n3 2.35', '1 4.70\n2 3.25\n3 1.85', '1 2.20\n2 3.00\n3 3.20']
```

So need to remove 1 at the start of the array, 2 in \n2, and 3 in \n3 for each.
Results need to be

```
array = ['1.60\n3.90\n5.40', '3.45\n3.10\n2.35', '4.70\n3.25\n1.85', '2.20\n3.00\n3.20']
```

Comment: You can use a regular expression that matches the initial digits. You can use `element.split(' ')[1]` to get everything after the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RegEx, for this particular case:

```
 import re

 yourarray = ['1 1.60\n2 3.90\n3 5.40', '1 3.45\n2 3.10\n3 2.35', '1 4.70\n2 3.25\n3 1.85', '1 2.20\n2 3.00\n3 3.20']

 newarray = [re.sub(r"^[0-9] |[0-9] ", '', yourarray[i]) for i in range(len(yourarray))]

 print (newarray)
```

Output:

```
 ['1.60\n3.90\n5.40', '3.45\n3.10\n2.35', '4.70\n3.25\n1.85', '2.20\n3.00\n3.20']
```

Comment: Thank you @Ruggero, but this removes only first. I need to remove 2 in \n2 and 3 in \n3

Comment: @MareS992 ok, edited.

Comment: Amazing man. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MareS992 This solution will not find 2+ digit counters (10 11 ...)...

Comment: @arutar, Hmm... "counting numbers" implicitly includes multi-digit, but example was explicitly single-digit.

Comment: @arutar Indeed, I wrote _for this particular case_

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

array = ['1 1.60\n2 3.90\n3 5.40', '1 3.45\n2 3.10\n3 2.35', '1 4.70\n2 3.25\n3 1.85', '1 2.20\n2 3.00\n3 3.20']

array1=[]
array1.extend(re.sub('\d+ ','',x) for x in array)
```

output

```
['1.60\n3.90\n5.40', '3.45\n3.10\n2.35', '4.70\n3.25\n1.85', '2.20\n3.00\n3.20']
```

Comment: i fixed my code @MareS992

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> ['\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.split()[1], e.splitlines())) for e in array]
['1.60\n3.90\n5.40', '3.45\n3.10\n2.35', '4.70\n3.25\n1.85', '2.20\n3.00\n3.20']
```

Or,

```
>>> ['\n'.join([x.split(maxsplit=1)[1] for x in e.splitlines()]) for e in array]
# same
```